# Do I need to apply a mirror modifier before exporting to Unity?

Tags: export, unity, mirror

I exported my character without applying mirror modifier and it seems it works well in both situation. Will it make any differences?

Comment: Exporting in formats like .dae, .fbx, .obj has `Apply Modifiers` option, and in some cases it's checked by default. In this case the modifier has been applied automatically (even without your action). If it hadn't I think you would have noticed that.

Comment: ok, you can add your comment as answer. thanks.

Answer (score 4):

In exporting options, you may see that in many cases there is *Apply modifiers* option, and often it is ticked by default:

[image]

<sub>Example is for .ply, the same behaviour is in case of exporting to .fbx, .obj, .x3d. 
Note: default options of Blender itself also may be changed.</sub>

In this case your exported objects/s will be actually mirrored without your action.
With that option unticked you will notice difference because if not applied, modifiers change how [the object is displayed and rendered, but not actual geometry](https://www.blender.org/manual/fr/modeling/modifiers/introduction.html#modifiers).

Comment: can you please check the link on your answer?

Comment: @cegaton thanks for notifying, don't know how could that happen, for some reason I didn't check it after including in the answer.